# R - linear regression get n value

Tags: r

I am performing linear regressions in R using the lm function. How do I get the n value for my results?

I'm doing summary(lm(y ~ b1 + b2))

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll need to provide a few more details to get the help you're looking for.  For example: (1) What do you mean by `the n value`?  (2) Please provide a working example.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Dubiouse data
y <- 1:10
b <- runif(10)
b1 <- runif(10)
b2 <- runif(10)
Model <- lm(y~ b1+b2)
#if n=number of samples then n is
length(Model$residuals)
[1] 10
```

Comment: If that's really what OP needs, why not just `length(y)`?

Comment: I dunno tbh. I guess this was just to exemplify how to get it from a "lm" class.